# Django Polls App clickable radio buttons?

Tags: php, html, django

I've recently finished the Django polls tutorial, now I'm trying to make clickable links out of the radio choices buttons on the detail.html page.

I've tried about everything but can't seem to get it to work. Could anyone send me in the right direction?

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
     <a href="{% url 'choice' %}"/> {% endfor %} <input type="submit" value="Vote" /> </form>
```

[image: code]

Edit 1: I tried adding, but that doesn't work.

```
 <a href="https://www.google.com">Test</a>
```

**For clarification I'm trying to make every choice a clickable link (href)**

Comment: provide the  error message or describe in short

Comment: `<a>` is not a self closing tag use `<a href="some_link">something</a>`.

Comment: Unfortunately this still does not work, I've tried adding <a href="http://google.com">google<a/>